# How to handling completion of multiple asynchronous messages and ensuring exactly-once semantic in Flink Statefun

Tags: async-await, apache-flink, fault-tolerance, flink-statefun

I'm trying to add more functionality to the example of [flink-statefun-playground/java/shopping-cart](https://github.com/apache/flink-statefun-playground/tree/main/java/shopping-cart) and have two questions:

**1.How to implement the functionality of waiting for completion of multiple asynchronous messages.**

For example, if Microservice A needs to send message `b` to multiple instances (B1, B2, B3) of Microservice B after A receiving message `a`. Each instance of B returns message `c` to A after processing message `b`. A can proceed only when it receives message `c` from all instances of B (B1, B2, B3). How should I handle this?

My current idea is to use a state variable in A to track the received message list (e.g., `{"B1": "not received", "B2": "received", "B3": "not received"}`). A can proceed when all values in the message list are marked as "received". However, I'm concerned about efficiency, especially if A may receives new messages `a` while waiting. Does StateFun provide support for handling the completion of multiple asynchronous messages efficiently in **Java**, or do you have any suggestions?

**2.How to achieve full exact-once semantic.**

As README in shopping cart example mentions, *"This example uses an egress in exactly-once mode."* How and where is this explicitly declared and ensured in the example? Besides, In the example, should we also add a replayable event source for ingress like Kafka to achieve this exact-once guarantee?  Otherwise, how does this semantics work if the request is lost?

Thank you for your assistance!